# Error while trying to deserialize a message using XRMServiceToolkit in CRM 2011 UR 12

Tags: javascript, performance, serialization, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I upgraded from UR 11 to UR 12 this week and when testing my environment im coming up with some issues. I already ran the Custom Code Validation Tool and fixed most of the possible JS related issues and changed the code to use XrmServiceToolkit instead of CrmServiceToolkit. Below is the message im getting everytime I try and save and my JS run a XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Create() of a Service Activity (SA) record. The message I believe is related to the assignment of a team record to the owner field of the SA, since if I remove this assignment the error doesnt appear.

What can be the issue causing this?

Ive seen a couple of issues like this but related to plugins and not to JS. I also diabled all custom plugins that would run on a creation of a SA so no plugins should be firing at the same time of the Create being done.

```
Microsoft Dynamics CRM Error Report Contents

<CrmScriptErrorReport>
<ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
<ScriptErrorDetails>
<Message>The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message:   There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:entity. The InnerException message  was 'Error in line 1 position 883. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:team'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'team' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</Message>
<Line>1622</Line>
<URL>/%7B635422648580003236%7D/WebResources/rst_XrmServiceToolkit</URL>
<PageURL>/userdefined/edit.aspx?etc=112&id=%7bF9288110-D780-F54A-51C9-BB67A8F69A6D%7d&pagemode=iframe</PageURL>
```

I've also run the diagnostic tool while saving this record:

Diagnostic Tool Trace Details:

```
[2014-08-06 15:31:24.545] Process: w3wp |Organization:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Thread:   21 |Category: Platform.Sdk |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 |Level: Error |ReqId: b84df6d9-3038-4aae-a63f-3b58e8db4c8c | ServiceModelTraceRedirector.TraceData  ilOffset = 0x45
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspxHandling an exception. Exception details: System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:entity. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 871. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:team'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'team' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 871. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:team'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'team' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadKeyValuePairOfstringanyTypeFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadAttributeCollectionFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadEntityFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract& dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-130517440714266137System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:entity. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 871. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:team'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'team' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException: The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts/Services:entity. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 871. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:team'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'team' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details. ---&gt; System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 871. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:team'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'team' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadKeyValuePairOfstringanyTypeFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadAttributeCollectionFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadEntityFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameters(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo[] parts, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeBody(XmlDictionaryReader reader, MessageVersion version, String action, MessageDescription messageDescription, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeBodyContents(Message message, Object[] parameters, Boolean isRequest)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationFormatter.DeserializeRequest(Message message, Object[] parameters)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.DeserializeInputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089Error in line 1 position 871. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:team'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'team' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadKeyValuePairOfstringanyTypeFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadAttributeCollectionFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadEntityFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Error in line 1 position 871. Element 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic:value' contains data from a type that maps to the name 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema:team'. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this name. Consider changing the implementation of the ResolveName method on your DataContractResolver to return a non-null value for name 'team' and namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadKeyValuePairOfstringanyTypeFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadAttributeCollectionFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString , XmlDictionaryString , CollectionDataContract )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, String name, String ns)
at ReadEntityFromXml(XmlReaderDelegator , XmlObjectSerializerReadContext , XmlDictionaryString[] , XmlDictionaryString[] )
at System.Runtime.Serialization.ClassDataContract.ReadXmlValue(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, XmlObjectSerializerReadContext context)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator reader, String name, String ns, Type declaredType, DataContract&amp; dataContract)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.InternalDeserialize(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Type declaredType, DataContract dataContract, String name, String ns)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.InternalReadObject(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObjectHandleExceptions(XmlReaderDelegator reader, Boolean verifyObjectName, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)
at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractSerializer.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, Boolean verifyObjectName)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.PartInfo.ReadObject(XmlDictionaryReader reader, XmlObjectSerializer serializer)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DataContractSerializerOperationFormatter.DeserializeParameterPart(XmlDictionaryReader reader, PartInfo part, Boolean isRequest)
```

Added the code below that causes this error. The part where I assign the owner is the one that causes the first desrialization error (The owner I'm assigning is a team). If I comment out this part then the part where I create the Activity Party for the equipment also causes an error.

```
CreateServiceActivity = function (aszServiceGUID, aiIsSavingMode) {

var oTempSA = GetServiceActivityData(aszServiceGUID);
var oSA = new XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.BusinessEntity("serviceappointment");

if (oTempSA.attributes["serviceid"] != null) {
    oSA.attributes["serviceid"] = oTempSA.attributes["serviceid"].id;
    oSA.attributes["subject"] = oTempSA.attributes["serviceid"].name;
}

if (oTempSA.attributes["ownerid"] != null) {

    //HERE IS WHERE A TEAM IS ASSIGNED TO THE SA. oTempSA also has a team as an owner        so it passes this same owner to the new SA.
    var oOwnerObject = new Object();
    oOwnerObject.type = oTempSA.attributes["ownerid"].entityType;
    oOwnerObject.value = oTempSA.attributes["ownerid"].id;
    oSA.attributes["ownerid"] = oOwnerObject;

}


//GET DEFAULT RESOURCE

var szDefaultResourceFetchXml = "<fetch mapping='logical'>" +
                    "<entity name='equipment'>" +
                    "<attribute name='name' />" +
                    "<attribute name='equipmentid' />" +
                    "<filter>" +
                        "<condition attribute='name' operator='eq' value='Default' />" +
                    "</filter>" +
                    "</entity>" +
                "</fetch>";
var szDefaultResourceFetchResults = CrmServiceToolkit.Fetch(szDefaultResourceFetchXml);
if (szDefaultResourceFetchResults.length > 0) {

    //THIS IS WHERE THE OTHER ERROR APPEARS IF OWNER CODE IS COMMENTED.
    var oActivityParty = new Object();
    oActivityParty.partyid = new Object();
    oActivityParty.partyid.type = "equipment";
    //oActivityParty.partyid.typecode = "4000";        
    oActivityParty.partyid.value = szDefaultResourceFetchResults[0].getValue('equipmentid');

    var oActivityPartyList = new Array();
    oActivityPartyList[0] = new Object();
    oActivityPartyList[0].activityparty = oActivityParty;

    oSA.attributes["resources"] = oActivityPartyList;

}

//GET DEFAULT STATUS
var szDefaulStatusFetchXml = "";
if (oSA.attributes["rst_account"] != null || oSA.attributes["rst_account"] != null) {
    szDefaulStatusFetchXml = "<fetch mapping='logical'>" +
                            "<entity name='rst_serviceactivitystatus'>" +
                                "<attribute name='rst_statusname' />" +
                                "<attribute name='rst_serviceactivitystatusid' />" +
                                "<filter type='or'>" +
                                    "<condition attribute='rst_code' operator='eq' value='" + rst_Global_Constants.SERVICEACTIVITYSTATUS_CODE_ASSIGNED() + "' />" +
                                "</filter>" +
                            "</entity>" +
                        "</fetch>";
}

szDefaulStatusFetchXmlResults = CrmServiceToolkit.Fetch(szDefaulStatusFetchXml);
if (szDefaulStatusFetchXmlResults.length > 0) {
    oSA.attributes["rst_serviceactivitystatusid"] = szDefaulStatusFetchXmlResults[0].getValue('rst_serviceactivitystatusid');
    oSA.attributes["rst_statuschangedatetime"] = new Date();
}

if (aiIsSavingMode == rst_Global_Constants.FORM_SAVEMODE_SAVE()) {
    //SAVE                     
    var createResponse = XrmServiceToolkit.Soap.Create(oSA);
}
```

}

Comment: please post the javascript code

Comment: Any ideas Guido on the JS Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this question it took me a while to figure it out but finally I got it. The mistake I made was assuming that my error was from the upgrade from CRM 2011 UR 11 to UR 12. I though that my problem was with the instalation of the UR in terms of the application and system wise thinking I had messed up somewhere or was missing a step. Sadly , I failed to take into consideration initially, the technicalities that would come from changing CRMServiceToolkit to XrmServiceToolkit.

This took me some time to notice and a complete installation of CRM 2011 in a new testing server to find out. In this installation I tested my solution in UR 11 without any other changes to the system which worked perfectly and then did an upgrade to UR 12 without any other variables that could affect the system. When I did the upgrade and started noticing the same error I knew the installation wasn't the issue but something else.

After various debugging steps using Fiddler2 and google searches finally realized that my issue was with the way I was setting up the fields in Javascript that were then being serialized by the XrmServiceToolkit library and then sent to CRM. After correctly changing my javascript from the old CRMServiceToolkit way of going about it I was able to slowly but surely fix all my code so that the Service Activity would be created without any issues.

Example for EntityReferences,

```
var oOwnerObject = new Object();
oOwnerObject.type = oTempSA.attributes["ownerid"].entityType;
oOwnerObject.value = oTempSA.attributes["ownerid"].id;
oSA.attributes["ownerid"] = oOwnerObject;
```

changed to

```
    oSA.attributes["ownerid"] = {
        id: oTempSA.attributes["ownerid"].id,
        logicalName: oTempSA.attributes["ownerid"].entityType,
        type: 'EntityReference'
    };
```

where `logicalname` and `type` had to be correctly set.

Another example, for Activity Parties I had to use

```
    //Create new Array with EntityCollection Type
    var partylist = new Array();
    partylist.type = 'EntityCollection';
    //Create object in array to define what in the partylist. 
    partylist[0] = new Object();
    partylist[0].id = szDefaultResourceFetchResults[0].getValue('equipmentid'); //Guid (i.e., Guid of User or Contact etc)
    partylist[0].name = szDefaultResourceFetchResults[0].getValue('name'); //Name (i.e., Name of User or Contact etc)
    partylist[0].logicalName = "equipment"; //entity schema name of account or contact
    //Assign Value
    oSA.attributes["resources"] = partylist;
```

Following these examples I fixed the rest of the issues on my Javascript and was able to have my code run successfully.